# Strange "scrolling" behavior in Chrome 48 on iOS 9.2.1 / iPhone 5S when navigating from one page to another while scrolling down on the first page

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome

I noticed that when I scroll down a bit on the first page, then I click on a link that takes me to the second page, on the second page Chrome already scrolled down a bit. It seems it scrolls down approximately as much as I scroll down on the first page.

Is this by design or why is it behaving like this?

Page 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />

    <link href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="/pf.html">TAKE ME TO pf.html</a>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />

    <link href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
                            srcset="/img/landscape/large.jpg 1772w,
                    /img/landscape/medium.jpg 886w,
                    /img/landscape/small.jpg 443w"
                            sizes="100w" />

                    <source srcset="/img/portrait/large.jpg 955w,
                    /img/portrait/medium.jpg 640w,
                    /img/portrait/small.jpg 320w"
                            sizes="100vw" />

                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/landscape/medium.jpg" alt="" />
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem... Anyone has any idea?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the latest Chrome on iOS. Several people have reported the same issue in Apple AppStore.